# ERROR LTSpice from V tp gV

Tags: ltspice, sinusoidal

i have a problem here, it should be a sin but here is what i get and the Vin is in V and Vout is in Giga-Volt, which is wrong, what should I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you have 470 farad (C3), 47 farad (C4) and 270 farad (C5) capacitors? Also, you're using the ideal op-amp which, AFAIK, can give you physically meaningless results (gigavolts).

Comment: is it normal to ge from Volt to Giga Volts?

Comment: what should i do instead 470 farad (C3), 47 farad (C4) and 270 farad (C5) capacitors?

Comment: 1) No, it's not normal. 2) Replace them with capacitors of correct values (I assume you want 470 uF, 47 uF and 270 uF).

Comment: still... it supposed to be a sin but it's not

Comment: what should i do when it's not normal? thank you so much for your help

Comment: "It is supposed to be a sin [sic]" but you have nothing that can generate sine waves there. To be honest, your circuit is a mess, maybe break it down in parts (power supply, filtering, amplification) with a clear input/output path will help you get it working.

Comment: idk how can i do this, it's my first time using LTSpice

Comment: Is this based on another design, or are you designing this yourself?  If you have a reference, it will help.

Comment: no, it's based on another designing, i just remaking it

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi do you have the original design?

Comment: yes, i do, and it's the same as the one i made but still doesn't work